# How to give a background video only to a particular div or class .

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

i.e i want to give a video in place of slider or banner images in front page of the website . In the below code i want to apply the video as a background only To 'video' class , how can i do it please help me out , thank you .

```
<body>
    <div class="video">
        <nav>
        </nav>
        <div class="some-text">
            <h1> welcome </h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

        <!-- here there other content of the site where the video should not appear in background   -->

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I try browsing to help the solution you This may help you
[Fullscreen HTML5 Page Background Video](https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/knqyK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
var myVideo = document.getElementById("vd");
myVideo.play();
```

```css
.videoBg {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.videoBg video{
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

video{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="videoBg">
      <video id="vd">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video> 
    </div>

    <div class="container">
your content
        <!-- here there other content of the site where the video should not appear in background   -->

    </div>

</body>
```